# Why does JScript URL work differently in VS, then when published

Tags: jquery, visual-studio-2012

I have this which works in Visual Studio.  It does not work when Published:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "Order/EditLineItem",
        data: { id: dataItem.id },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data); // 
        }
```

This, on the other hand, works when published, but not in Visual Studio:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/PropertySearch/Order/EditLineItem",
        data: { id: dataItem.id },
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#content').html(data); // 
        }
```

The only difference is adding the site name "PropertySearch" at the start of the URL.

Is there some way to write this so that it works in both?

This is the current route:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Order", action = "Start", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

Comment: Yes, make sure that your development environment has the same root/subfolder structure as your production environment. The fact that this doesn't work suggests that the page making the ajax requests exists in a different folder when published than it does when you're in visual studio relative to the EditLineItem script.

Comment: Yes, your right.  When published it the app runs in it's own folder on the server.  When in VS, there is no such subfolder. I can't change the published location, so is there some way to configure VS to run from a subfolder?

Comment: Found the answer: You can add a virtual directory in the Project Properties.  Once I did this to match the server directory, it worked fine.

Comment: I would post an answer, but i think you can better explain how to fix it since i'm not very familiar with visual studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer here is to:

1. Go to Project Property Page.
2. Web Tab
3. Find "Virtual Path:" and enter the site name.

Then when you run in VS, you will see the Virtual Path in the Browser address bar appended to the root.

Works for me.